# How to give a button iPhone onScreenKeyboard return key behaviour?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-storyboard, ui-design

I have an application where I have to implement customised QuickType Suggestion at the top of onScreen Keyboard. Where(QuickType Suggestion Box) the right button behaviour is like as that keyboard return type behaviour. If the keyBoard return key is "next" then the suggestion's right key will be "next", if "Done" then it also has to be "Done" along with the type action.
I had attested three buttons along with the top of that keyboard when it's appear. But I can't figure out, how to work with it?
Is it possible to do with this trick? and how?
If, there another ways to do that, please suggest.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, it's not currently possible to do that. What you could do is to hide the autocorrection bar (`someTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;`) and implement one by yourself.

Comment: yes, I did that. What is showing now it's a customised one not the default.

Comment: Is there no way to give the upper "next" button action as the Keyboard "Next" button action?  @AlejandroIván

Comment: what action are you trying to do exactly , i mean when clicking on next what is the expected behavior @AyonChowdhury  ?

Comment: I can't test it right now but maybe this could help: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/returnKeyType

Comment: The expected behaviour is like if I hit the Next button of the suggestion than it will resign from the current textField and respond to the next textField. @AlejandroIván

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following way worked for me:

-(IBAction)customNextButtonAction:(id)sender {

```
 for (UITextField *textField in [self.textFieldContainingView subviews]) {
     if ([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] && textField == self.desiredTextField) {
        [self.desiredTextField resignFirstResponder];
        UIView *next = self.nextTextField;
        [next becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

}

Thanks all to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Okey so first you need to know what is the type of your keyboard button and if the button is next then your text fields should have a unique tag foreach one :

```
-(IBAction)didTapOnCustomNextButton:(id)sender
{
    UITextField * textField = (UITextField *)sender ;

    if(textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyNext)
    {
       NSInteger nextTextField = textField.tag+1;

       UIResponder* responder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTextField];

       if (responder!=nil) 
       {
          [responder becomeFirstResponder];
       } 
       else 
       {
         [textField resignFirstResponder];
       }
    }
    else
    {
       [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }

}
```

**Edit 1:**
i edited my code to work in an IBAction and also fixed some variables names

Comment: textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyNext it's causing crash


log:
[UIButton returnKeyType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb2ec81cb70
2015-08-25 11:09:17.196 testingApp[835:39808] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton returnKeyType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb2ec81cb70'

Answer (score 1):

1.first, you need to find what is your `textfield` returnkeytype and then make a Barberton on toolbar according to it.

```
-(void)customizeToolbarMethod
  {
     if(textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyNext)
       {
        UIBarButtonItem *barBtnPrev = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next"
                                                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                          target:self action:@selector(actionBtnNextForPassword)];
       }
    else if(textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyDone)
       {
    UIBarButtonItem *barBtnDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                                      target:self action:@selector(actionResignKeyBoard)];
       }  
 //set this bar button onto your toolbar by making them array of bar-button
  } 
-(void) actionBtnNextForPassword
 {
           //do what you want to do......
 }
-(void)actionResignKeyBoard
 {
           //do what you want to do......
 }
```

Comment: but the above keyboard buttons are not BarButtonItem, all are UIButton in a view.  @Lea-rner

Comment: @AyonChowdhury u want a toolbar above the keyboard ??, if yes so it alway better to have bar buttons instead of button because positioning of the buttons is difficult to control uitoolbar.if u wanna proper code then i will edit the above answer for u

Comment: Thanx for your help, I did it.